# Will dumping capacitor power into a coil cause overheating

Tags: power, capacitor, temperature, coil, discharge

I have a cap 450Vdc @ 480uF if will a 1Ω coil become significantly hot (well above 25°c) if I discharge the cap from 100% to ~0% 3x / second into the coil?

If not then what would be theoretical capacitor which would cause the coil to become significantly hotter than 25°c at the same discharge condistion?

**Update:** 
Coil inductance = 3mH
Voltage across cap = 450V

What was not mentioned in the answers was the fact the power pulses from the capacitor are microseconds long - thus the average power over a few seconds is negligible or am I missing something?

Comment: What are the voltage across the capacitor and the coil inductance? From them, you can calculate how much energy is dissipated by the coil resistance for a given time.

Comment: The answer (singular) is valid independent of the pulse length. Given 450uF, 3mH, 1 ohm and a switch, you can simulate what happens when the switch closes and see pulse shapes and peak powers.

Answer (score 1):

The energy stored in a capacitor is \$\frac{1}{2}CV^2\$.

In your case it is:
\$\frac{1}{2}(480\text{ µF})(450\text{ V})^2=48.6\text{ J}\$

If you are going to discharge 48.6 J three times per second, then that's \$48.6×3=145.8\text{ W}\$

---

I do not know *exactly* how large your 1 Ω coil is. Or rather, I do not know the [\$R_{θJA}\$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_temperature). You can acquire the \$R_{θJA}\$, if you dissipate a known power in the coil and measure the temperature rise. Dissipate 1 W for long enough for the temperature to stabilise, and then measure the temperature rise and there you have a good value for \$R_{θJA}\$.

But **I am fairly certain** that *most* things that dissipates 145.8 W will heat up fairly quickly to very high temperatures.

My guesstimate for the steady state temperature of your coil is well above 25° Celsius. It will *probably* be dangerous to hold with your bare hands.